# How can i make shopify gird view and list view?

Tags: list, filter, grid, shopify

How can i make shopify gird view and list view? I already done html and collection-list.liquid for list view.

Here is the button code-->

```
<div class="collection-view">
 <button type="button" title="Grid view" class="change-view{% unless template contains 'list' %} change-view--active{% endunless %}" data-view="grid">
<span class="icon-fallback-text">
  <span class="icon icon-grid-view" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="fallback-text">Grid View</span>
</span>
```

List View

I need jquery or javascript code for control the gird view and list view on shopify.

example button--> http://prntscr.com/8lfkvh

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class using JavaScript to the `.collection-view` using a `click` event of one of the buttons to toggle between the two different views.